# Updating Path in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-graphics

I have got a SwiftUI View with a chart which is made using Path and data from `entries` array.

The code:

```
struct TodayChartView: View {
    var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                    Path { p in
                            for i in 1..<entries.count {
                                p.move(to: CGPoint(x: entries[i-1].x, entries[i-1].y: y))
                                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(entries[i].x: x, entries[i].y: y))
                            }
                        }
                    }.stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                }
}
```

When user presses the button in another View, a new entry is added to `entries` and I want to display it on my Path. So, basically, I need to somehow trigger redrawing it. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `entries` as a parameter to `TodayChartView`.  With the `entries` as a `@State var` in `ContentView`, the `TodayChartView` gets redrawn whenever `entries` changes.

Here is a complete example (tested in Xcode 11.7):

```
struct TodayChartView: View {
    let entries: [CGPoint]
    
    var body: some View {
        // GeometryReader { reader in
            Path { p in
                for i in 1..<self.entries.count {
                    p.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.entries[i-1].x, y: self.entries[i-1].y))
                    p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.entries[i].x, y: self.entries[i].y))
                }
            }
            .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        // }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var entries: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Add Point") {
                let x = CGFloat.random(in: 0...300)
                let y = CGFloat.random(in: 0...300)
                self.entries.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
            TodayChartView(entries: self.entries)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Your `TodayChartView` is not currently using `GeometryReader` so I've commented it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    Path { p in
            for i in 1..<entries.count {
                p.move(to: CGPoint(x: entries[i-1].x, entries[i-1].y: y))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(entries[i].x: x, entries[i].y: y))
            }
        }
    }.stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    .id(entries)     // << here !!
```